# Has any country ever diverted an international flight in order to arrest a wanted person?

Tags: aircraft, law-enforcement

Belarus recently [came under scrutiny](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-57219860) for forcing a Ryanair plane to divert so they could capture a wanted person on board:

> A Ryanair plane from Greece to Lithuania was diverted to Belarus for
> several hours on Sunday, with activists saying it was done to arrest a
> dissident journalist on board.
>
> European nations reacted with outrage, accusing Belarus of "state
> terrorism".
>
> The ex-editor of the Nexta group, Roman Protasevich, was detained
> before the plane was allowed to resume its flight. *[BBC](https://www.nationnews.com/2021/05/24/plane-diverted-journalist-detained/)*

Is this the first time an incident like this happened?

Comment: I think grounded doesn't quite cover this case. Grounding a plane sounds to me like denying permission for take off. In this case, the government of Belarus intervened to force the plane to land when it flew over its territory. Not really sure what word captures that situation though. Changed it a bit, feel free to go with something else if you think it fits better.

Comment: The EU called it "unprecedented'. I'm pretty sure it is in the West in the past 50 years or so. Before the 1944 Chicago Convention, perhaps such cases were more common, not sure.

Comment: @phoog yeah I’ve always thought grounding a plane to capture someone is not too uncommon but can’t find any other examples for some reason.

Comment: If you're thinking about people who were unruly on-board, resulting in the plane being diverted, then there are plenty of examples though. However, in this case Belarus claimed there was a bomb threat and sent a jet figher... that is surely out of the ordinary. It's these actions that caused the EU countries to call for Belarus' airspace to be declared unsafe.

Comment: Apparently "the last dictator" took personal credit (!) for ordering the jet fighter in action "Lukashenko personally ordered the warplane to escort the Ryanair Boeing to Minsk, state news agency BelTA reported." https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/belarus-forces-ryanair-plane-land-detain-opposition-blogger-n1268270 And if the bomb threat were actually real, I'm pretty sure L wouldn't have given a hoot given that the plane was almost out of B territory https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/E508/production/_118623685_athens_flight_diverted_2x640-nc.png

Comment: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5811/is-this-question-better-on-the-history-se Meta discussion on whether this question should be on the History.SE.

Comment: NOTE:  This question was migrated after discussion; please assist OP to revise the question to fit within our scope.

Comment: Overall, nothing particularly remarkable about this incident . Every country retains sovereignty over its airspace. Unfortunately, there were incidents were passenger planes were shoot down by various militaries. KAL007, Iran Air Flight 655, MH17 etc ... Compared to those incidents, this is relatively benign .

Comment: [bbc](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-57240770) examines the same question

Comment: @rs.29 just because countries have sovereignty doesn’t mean they often exercise it in this manner. Something can be legal and still remarkable.

Comment: @Tim Remarkable for daily politics and propaganda . From historical perspective unfortunately no.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

By Googling "Snowden"+"Ryanair Belarus" I've found four more relevant examples. One story from 2010 seems to be a [direct equivalent](https://www.rferl.org/a/Kyrgyzstan_Confirms_Iran_Intercepted_Plane_Arrested_Two_Passengers/1967264.html) to what happened in Belarus:

> Taalaibek Turumbekov, deputy chief of Kyrgyzstan Aba Joldoru, the national airline, told RFE/RL that a plane flying from Dubai was made to land in the southern Iranian city of Bandar Abbas on February 23, **escorted by two Iranian jets**.
> Iranian authorities announced on February 23 that that they had seized the leader of the Sunni rebel group Jundallah, Abdolmalek Rigi, on a flight from Dubai to Bishkek.

The other is only tangentially related because the [plane never left Ukraine](https://tass.com/world/908127):

> MINSK, October 22 2016. Belarus has protested against Ukraine's actions to return by force on October 21 a Belavia plane to Kiev. The republic's Foreign Ministry summoned Ukraine's Charge d'Affairs in Belarus Valery Dzhigun, the Belarusian Foreign Ministry said in a statement released on Saturday.
> The Belarusian company said the dispatcher told the captain "**in case of disobeying the order, fighters will take off**." As the plane landed at the Ukrainian airport, the local law enforcers detained a passenger, who is a citizen of Armenia. After the refueling, the plane left for Minsk and later on landed there safely. Later on, the law enforcers released the man and he took an evening flight to Minsk.

Finally, [Turkey forced a Syrian plane](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2012/10/11/russia-demands-turkey-explain-intercepted-jet/) to land in 2012 but that seems to have been motivated by military cargo rather than arresting someone on board:

> Moscow has accused Ankara of endangering Russian lives after Turkey forced a Syrian passenger plane to land and seized what it suspected was military equipment being ferried from Russia to Syrian President Bashar al-Assad.
> Military jets escorted the Damascus-bound Airbus A-320,which was carrying around 30 passengers from Moscow, into Ankara airport late on Wednesday after Turkey received intelligence that it was carrying “non-civilian cargo”.

There was also a [controversial story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achille_Lauro_hijacking#Interception_of_EgyptAir_jet) involving the interception of an Egyptian jet by the US Airforce but that involved a chartered plane rather than a scheduled flight.

Comment: Interestingly the US [denied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrest_of_Abdolmalek_Rigi#Arrest_operation) that the Iranian/Kyrgyzstan version of the events took place. Or at least that Iran arrested whom they claimed to have arrested on that flight.

Answer (score 19):

I'll note here that the Morales' plane story is much more complicated that it's made to be in the other answer. It was apparently a false flag operation to a good extent, misleading the Westerners as to whom was on-board; or at least Assange [claimed](https://www.democracynow.org/2015/5/28/assange_on_the_untold_story_of) he did that. Anyway, the  Morales plane landed in Austria because [its crew claimed](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2013/07/tale-re-routed-bolivian-presidents-plane-falling-apart/313528/) it could not read its fuel gauges:

> > Control tower: Do you need any assistance?
> >
> > Pilot: Not at this moment. We need to land because we cannot get a correct indication of the fuel indication so as a precaution we need to land.
>
> Why the plane landed in Austria isn't clear, but it doesn't seem to have been at the insistence of the Austrians.

Then Morales declared outrage for being "forced" to land.

The issue whether the plane was actually denied airspace entry (and by whom) is a bit more murky. At least France clearly apologized, but Spain the plane was actually due to land for refueling (Canary Islands, actually) never made a clear statement. It is known that Portugal granted overflight some days before, but refused the request to refuel on their territory. (I'll spare you the quotes on that.) So it's not really a clear-cut situation like a jet fighter showing up and requesting the plane land.

Also the reports whether the Morales' plane was searched are fairly contradictory. An Austrian minister initially said yes, but after Bolivians denied that took place, the details [came out](https://www.voanews.com/europe/austria-did-not-search-morales-jet-vienna-president-says) as:

> "Someone from the airport staff sought out the aircraft or the pilot after landing to inquire about the nature of the technical problem," [Austrian President Heinz] Fischer was quoted as saying.
>
> "The Austrian official was advised that the defect was already fixed, and saw on this occasion that the plane was empty... He did not look under the seats. There was no formal inspection, but no other people were found on board," Fischer added.
>
> Pressed on whether that meant Austrians had not searched the plane, he said, "There was no search in the forensic sense. There was also no reason to under international law. The plane of a president belongs to 'his territory' and cannot be searched readily."

N.B. Assange was aware of this too, as in the interview (first link) he said:

> from a legal perspective, they are flying embassies.

On the other hand, that does not mean countries [have to allow them](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-latin-america-23158242):

> Eurocontrol - which co-ordinates Europe's airspace and traffic control - said it was "a national decision whether or not to accept a state flight" under the terms of the Chicago Convention on International Civil Aviation.

But there's a [legal] difference between not allowing a flight to enter and forcing it to land.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question. Did you mean to post a comment for my answer?

Comment: @bytebuster: yep, because you're making a false equivalence in your answer. As far I can tell, Morales' plane could have returned to Moscow. Its crew chose to land in Austria.

Comment: @Tim Yes, but then it was an emergency landing, not a plane being diverted.

Comment: So basically the flight of the Bolivian President was forced to land so it could be searched by foreign officers, but the culprits managed to create so much confusion as to who did what, they can all pretend it was no big deal?

Comment: @Ivana No, It was neither forced to land nor searched.

Comment: @Ivana: also, by my estimates it had enough fuel to return to Russia instead of landing in Austria, because the scheduled refueling stop was in some Spanish island in the Atlantic Ocean.

Comment: Re *"but Spain the plane was actually"*: This doesn't compute. Is a word missing? Or something else?

Comment: Another major distinction, according to [the BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-57240770): *"The 1944 Chicago convention applies to civilian planes, such as the Ryanair flight, but not to state aircraft such as presidential or military planes."* Specifically, I think that means non-civilian planes have fewer rights of flying over so authorities may have more leeway in denying permission. I don't know the specifics, but I think it may be interesting angle regarding the Morales story.

Answer (score 18):

In 2013, Bolivia president's jet heading from Moscow, Russia was rerouted and forced to land in Austria in search for Edward Snowden;

- [Bolivian president’s plane forced to land in Austria in hunt for   Snowden](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/bolivian-presidents-plane-forced-to-land-in-austria-in-hunt-for-snowden/2013/07/03/c281c2f4-e3eb-11e2-a11e-c2ea876a8f30_story.html) — The Washington Post
- [Evo Morales grounding incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evo_Morales_grounding_incident) — Wikipedia

Comment: The wiki page you link to says something else "but was rerouted to Austria when France, Spain, Portugal and Italy **reportedly denied access to their airspace**, allegedly due to suspicions that Snowden was on board."  There are also conflicting reports on whether the plane was searched "Austria's deputy chancellor, Michael Spindelegger, said that the plane was searched, although the Bolivian Defense Minister denied a search took place, saying Morales had denied entry to his plane.".

Comment: @Fizz different method from the Belarusians but the result appears to be the same. If Snowden was on board he would've presumably been arrested.

Comment: @JonathanReez: the difference is that the Morales plane landed [because](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/jul/03/bolivia-un-evo-morales-plane) it could not complete its planned route with the fuel it had on board due to those airspace entry denials. Frankly it's a bit unclear why it didn't return to Moscow, as they had enough fuel for that. I've not heard an explanation for that. It seems they did land in Austria precisely so that they could claim "aggression" (as they knew Snowden was not actually on board).

Comment: @Fizz, did you mean that the plane was forced to land *in order to* arrest, but the actual search/arrest has not occurred, even if the spy was on board? I agree, this could be true. Why have you highlighted the "reportedly denied access to their airspace" in your comment then? Is it relevant?

Comment: @bytebuster Austria did not force the plane to land. The pilot requested emergency landing permission since it couldn't continue it's flight and needed to refuel. 2 compleatly different situations.

Comment: @JonathanReez agree. The european countries retracted, and denied the Bolivian plane for political reasons in the last moment. Therefore the airplane was basically trapped in EU airspace and had to land and refuel. The political motives seem clear. Who does really believe that if Snowden had been on the plane they would not have arrested him? Its interesting how the official Belarusian and Russian media reports now report that the airplane requested a landing for due to safety reasons, in a very similar way as the European media reported on the Bolivian airplane story.

Comment: @Hjan Right, instead of continuing their descending to land at their destination airport, the pilots desided to do ratical right curve with a sharp descention in height and fly 20 minutes east to Minsk for 'safety reasons'. *Who do you think you're kidding?*

Comment: @Hjan Based on the Austrian government statement made on the same day Morales landed in Vienna: 2013-07-02: *Interior Minister Johanna Mikl-Leitner declared: "An asylum application can only be made from Austrian territory".  Should Snowden manage to travel to Austria, however, he would **not be deported because there was no international arrest warrant against him**.* [Edward Snowden - Nicht akzeptierte Asylanträge – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Snowden#Nicht_akzeptierte_Asylantr%C3%A4ge)

Comment: @MarkJohnson its nice that the Austrian Interior Minister says that. Two weeks earlier the US requested Hongkong Authorities to execute an international arrest warrant. https://www.zeit.de/politik/ausland/2013-06/prism-usa-snowden-anklage?utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F The way EU countries tried to block the Airplane of the Bolivian president in mid-air, by revoking access fits the picture of suggesting that he would be welcome if he came to Austria and then they would change their mind. I also would not bet my life on such a statement, and neither did Mr. Snowden.

Comment: @Hjan No doubt this was a topic discussed when the Austrian President Fischer went to greet President Morales in his plane and shared breakfast with him. [Evo Morales grounding incident - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evo_Morales_grounding_incident#Forced_landing)

Comment: @Hjan Neither your source, nor the original [Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/us-charges-snowden-with-espionage/2013/06/21/507497d8-dab1-11e2-a016-92547bf094cc_story.html) article that it is quoting, says anything about an **international arrest warrant** (as you are claiming) but only of a **criminal complaint**.

Comment: @Hjan What Washington Post article states is: *By filing a **criminal complaint**, prosecutors have a legal basis to make the detention request of the authorities in Hong Kong. Prosecutors now have 60 days to file an indictment, probably under seal, and can then move to have Snowden extradited from Hong Kong for trial in the United States.*

Comment: Perhaps add to your answer who (effectively) forced it to land? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today).)

Answer (score 11):

[Interception of EgyptAir jet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achille_Lauro_hijacking#Interception_of_EgyptAir_jet):

- Terrorists murdered a US citizen
- Egypt let the terrorists fly out on a commercial (chartered) airplane
- US intercepted the flight in international airspace and made it land in Italy
- Italians released the mastermind but tried the terrorists (calling them "soldiers fighting for their ideals")

Comment: Small correction: it was a chartered plane, not a scheduled flight

Comment: Also, the interception took place in international airspace. It was a chartered flight. The only other people on-board were (strangely) some Egyptian counter-terrorism agents. Also, the plane ended up over international waters because it was refused permission to land at Tunis, where it was initially headed for.

Answer (score 10):

There's an [article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-57240770) published by the BBC today on this very topic. It quotes three of the examples listed in the accepted answer, and this one from 1956:

> **1956: The arrest of the leaders of the Algerian independence movement**
>
> On 22 October 1956 five leaders of the Algerian independence movement, the FLN, were on a civilian flight from Rabat in Morocco to Tunis, reports BBC Arabic's Ahmed Rouaba. They were due to take part in a conference on the future of the Maghreb region hosted by then Tunisian President Habib Bourguiba.
>
> Algeria was a French colony at the time and the French secret service sent fighter jets to intercept the passenger plane, forcing it to land in Algeria.
>
> The events sparked anger in Morocco and Tunisia.
>
> The five arrested included Ahmed Ben Bella, who went on to be Algeria's first president after it gained independence from France. He died in 2012 aged 95.

The same article notably says the Evo Morales grounding incident is not directly comparable, since 1) the aircraft wasn't forced to land by military interceptors, but rather by the airspace being closed, and 2) it was a state aircraft and not a civilian one that was involved. State aircraft are not covered by the Chicago convention.

Comment: I was going to post this as an answer but it seems from comments that the OP is looking for an example involving a scheduled passenger flight (although that is not stated in his question). As far as I can tell, the FLN people were the only passengers on board and the plane was provided by the sultan of Morocco. See [Détournement de l'avion du FLN](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9tournement_de_l%27avion_du_FLN) and [Arrestation des leaders du FLN](https://fresques.ina.fr/independances/fiche-media/Indepe00051/voyage-de-mohammed-v-a-tunis-et-arrestation-des-leaders-du-fln.html).

Answer (score 4):

[One instance from 1954](https://www.nytimes.com/1954/12/13/archives/syrian-airliner-seized-by-israel-plane-l0-aboard-is-forced-down.html), Syrian plane captured by Israel:

> TEL AVIV, Israel, Dec. 12 -A Syrian Airways Dakota was intercepted by Israeli fighter planes this morning and escorted to Lydda Airport. Four passengers' and five crew members were detained, but one passenger, an American citizen, was released.

[Second instance from 2010](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/montreal/man-removed-from-aeromexico-flight-sent-to-u-s-1.910970), involving a flight from Paris to Mexico City being forcefully diverted to Montreal:

> The passenger removed from an Aeromexico flight diverted to Montreal
> has been sent to the U.S., Canadian and American officials say.
> Abdirahman Ali Gaal was removed from the flight bound for Mexico City
> from Paris on Sunday at the request of U.S. officials.
> The Canada Border Services Agency and the U.S. Department of Homeland
> Security confirmed that he was turned over to U.S. officials at  4
> p.m. Tuesday.

[Third instance from 2016](https://armenpress.am/eng/news/864893) is related to a flight from Kiev to Minsk being grounded before it could reach the Belarus border:

> A Belarusian “Belavia” aircraft, en route from Kiev to Minsk, was
> forced to return to the Ukrainian airport under the threat of being
> intercepted by military jets. The reason of the forced landing was an
> Armenian citizen aboard the aircraft, Obozrevatel.com reported citing
> the airline’s press service.
>
> “The ground controller ordered the aircraft to immediately return to
> the airport after entering the airspace of Belarus 50km. No
> explanation was given. The ground controller reported in case of
> failing to fulfill the order fighter jets will be scrambled”, the
> statement of the airline company reads.

Comment: Whatever happened to Abdirahman Ali Gaal after he was sent to US? Google doesn't know.

Comment: Edit the answer a bit to avoid it being a link-only answer

Comment: As for Mr. Ali Gaal - [latest news](https://www.reuters.com/article/pressdigest-canada/press-digest-canada-july-7-idUKSGE6660DQ20100707) says he was granted parole and was allowed to return to his family in Seattle.